# Postfix rejects SASL auth when dovecot is down

Tags: postfix, smtp, authentication, dovecot, sasl

We're using Postfix with Dovecot and SASL Auth via Dovecot (based on [this](http://workaround.org/ispmail/squeeze) tutorial). All works like expected. But when Dovecot is down (i.e. for maintenance or other reasons) then clients could not authenticate at Postfix and Postfix rejects client requests because of `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` that follow after `permit_sasl_authenticated`.

Is there a ways to temporarily reject mails arriving at Postfix when Dovecot auth is down?
Our postfix conf is:

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = check_sender_auth
check_sender_auth =
   reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch,
   permit_sasl_authenticated,
   reject
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
   reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
   check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/check_sender_domains,
   reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
   [...]
```

`check_sender_domains` is a lookup table which return `check_sender_auth` for sender address claiming to be from us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change the reject_code for your submission listener to 450, so it is not a permanent reject but a defer.

```
check_sender_auth =
   defer_if_reject 
   reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch,
   permit_sasl_authenticated,
   reject
```

See http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#defer_if_reject for details.

Unfortunately, this is not simple to update when "dovecot goes down", which I admit has me puzzled; ***why*** does dovecot go down ?

If you experience outages due to dovecot maintenance, you should invest effort into not needing maintenance outages on dovecot.

Dovecot can run HA quite well; you could trivially run a secondary instance only for SASL (no IMAP services) on another box.

Comment: when asking my question, I just realized, that it has to do something with `reject` after `permit_sasl_authenticated`. I like the 5xx reject, because senders claiming to be from us would be rejected the hard way. But I believe you're right. I'll give a try to a 4xx code and give feedback